# Application object in microsoft excel object model

Tags: vbscript, excel.application

Today while practicing vb script i came up with a little doubt please help to clear my doubt. I have written this code and created a excel sheet in my D: drive

```
dim excel
SET excel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible=true
excel.application.Workbooks.Add
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs"D:\pushkar23.xls"
excel.quit
SET excel=nothing
```

But if I change the line

```
excel.application.Workbooks.Add
```

to

```
excel.Workbooks.Add
```

then still the sheet is created in my D: drive.
Please tell me if there is any difference between both methods.

Comment: No, there isn't `.Application.Workbooks.Add` is the same as `.Workbooks.Add`, only longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application_properties.aspx), you'll see that the Application object (and some others, e.g. Workbook) has an Application property that

> Returns an Application object that represents the creator of the
>   specified object

It's always the same:

Option Explicit

```
Dim oExcel : Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
WScript.Echo 0, CStr(oExcel Is oExcel.Application)
WScript.Echo 1, CStr(oExcel Is oExcel.Application.Application.Application)
Dim oWB : Set oWB = oExcel.Application.Application.Workbooks.Add
WScript.Echo 2, CStr(oWB.Application Is oExcel.Application)
oExcel.Quit
```

output:

```
0 True
1 True
2 True
```

For efficency and clarity, however, you should use plain oExcel wherever possible.